# Creating HTML table using nested for loops

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've been working on this for a day or so and I'm a bit stuck so I'm hoping I can come out of this with a clearer idea of what's going on.

Essentially I'm creating a HTML table using a nested for loop. The goal is to have a table that spans 7 columns per row.

```
var tbl = document.createElement("table");

for (var i = 15; i < 36; i++) {

    for (var j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
        var row = document.createElement("tr");
        var cell = document.createElement("td");
        var cellText = document.createTextNode(i);

        row.appendChild(cell);
        tbl.appendChild(row);

    }
    cell.appendChild(cellText);

}
$('#calendar').append(tbl);
```

Anticipated Result:

```
15 16 17 18 19 20 21
22 23 24 25 26 27 28
29 30 31 32 33 34 35
```

Actual Result:

```
15
16
17
18
19
20
21
22
23
...
35
```

Simplified the result for the sake of typing less but if anyone can please point me in the right direction, I'd love to know where I might going wrong with this. Thank you.

Comment: well you create a row every time so if you do not want a new row everytime what do you think you should do?

Comment: @epascarello I've been looking over this since posting it. My first thought is to pull the row variable out of the loop but rather than creating a row every single iteration, it just seems to be only creating one row now.

Comment: Yes, you need to pull it out of the nested loop, but than you keep appending the same row over and over inside the loop

Comment: Put it **between** the for loops.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*You can try like this*

```js
var calendar = document.getElementById('calendar');
var table    = document.createElement("table");                /*Create `table` element*/
var rows     = 3;
var cols     = 7;
var counter  = 15;
for (var i = 1; i <= rows; i++) {
 var tr = document.createElement("tr");                 /*Create `tr` element*/
 for (var j = 1; j <= cols; j++) {
     var td = document.createElement("td");             /*Create `td` element*/
     var cellText = document.createTextNode(counter);   /*Create text for `td` element*/
     ++counter;
     td.appendChild(cellText);                          /*Append text to `td` element*/
     tr.appendChild(td);                                /*Append `td` to `tr` element*/
 }
 table.appendChild(tr);                                 /*Append `tr` to `table` element*/
}
calendar.appendChild(table);                                   /*Append `table` to your HTML `calender` DIV*/
```

```html
<div id="calendar"></div>
```

Comment: your solution is more flexible, and optimized than mine.

Answer (score 1):

Here you are:
https://jsfiddle.net/0jvq1q0y/6/

```
var tbl = document.createElement("table");

for (var i = 15; i < 36; i++) {
if((i-15)%7==0)
            {
        var row = document.createElement("tr");
        tbl.appendChild(row);
            }
        var cell = document.createElement("td");
        var cellText = document.createTextNode(i);
        row.appendChild(cell);
            cell.appendChild(cellText);
}
$('#calendar').append(tbl);
```

Comment: I was actually getting really close to this solution. Thank you!